# Find appropriate f to satisfies $p_t-p_{xx}+p=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

It is a problem in my PDE course:

If h is a solution of $h_t-h_{xx}+h_x=0$ where  $ 0<x<l$.And $h(0,x)=\phi(x),h_x(t,0)=0,h_x(t,l)=0 $  Find $f$ s.t. $p=fh$ satisfies 
$p_t-p_{xx}+p=0$

Comment: $f(x,t) = 0$ for all $x,t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user112167 a nontrivial solution is better

Comment: When we look at the left equation we see that any solutions of the form $h(x,t)=at-ax=a(t-x)$ satisfies it. Now can you find an $f$ such that the right equation is satisfied?

Comment: @user112167 I have edited the question, sorry for that

Comment: In this case, I would say write $p_t-p_{xx}+p=0$ out in terms of $f$ and $h$ with the product rule. After that try if you can recognize $h_t-h_{xx}+h_x=0$ in it, and use the givens. Also I was reading $fh$ as $f\circ h$ or is it the product? Because a lot of people use this notation for both.

Comment: @user112167 it is the product

Answer (score 0):

Let $p=fh$. Let's just see what $p_t-p_{xx}+p$ works out to.

$$\begin{align}
p_t-p_{xx}+p &= (fh)_t-(fh)_{xx}+fh\\
&= fh_t+f_th-(fh_x+f_xh)_{x}+fh\\
&= fh_t+f_th-fh_{xx}-2f_xh_x-f_{xx}h+fh\\
\end{align}$$

Now grouping terms by $f$ derivatives:
$$\begin{align}
&= f(h_t-h_{xx}+h)+f_th-2f_xh_x-f_{xx}h\\
&= f(h_t-h_{xx}+h_x-h_x+h)+f_th-2f_xh_x-f_{xx}h\\
&= f(-h_x+h)+f_th-2f_xh_x-f_{xx}h\\
\end{align}$$

You want this to equal $0$ and you know nothing directly about $h$. So if we regroup by derivatives of $h$, it would be great if each coefficient works out to be $0$.

$$\begin{align}
&= h(f+f_t-f_{xx})-h_x(f+2f_x)\\
\end{align}$$

So you need 
$$\begin{align}
&\begin{cases}f+f_t-f_{xx}&=0\\
f+2f_x&=0
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

The second equation implies $f(x,t)=g(t)\,e^{-0.5x}$, which then makes the first equation reduce to

$$g+g_t-0.25g=0$$

Which implies $g(t)=C\,e^{-0.75t}$. So for some $C$, $$f(x,t)=C\,e^{-0.75t-0.5x}$$